# Jxbrowser upgrade to 4.3 - version check

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I was asked by a vendor to upgrade JxBrowser on 1 of our machines to 4.3.
How do I find out which version we currently have? and
How to upgrade to version 4.3

In addition this seems to be used mostly for Chrome and so do we still need to do this if we dont use chrome there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently used JxBrowser version can be known by simply looking which version of JAR are you using and the latest jar is jxbrowser-6.8.jar which means they are running on jxbrowser version-6.8. To upgrade to a newer version download the latest jars, include them in your class path and rebuild your application. Check their [site](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) for further clarifications and licencing.